# AngularJS filtrar por arreglo en propiedad del objeto

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy tratando de aplicar un filtro dentro de un ng-if, pero no doy con la solución.

Tengo un arreglo de objetos de este tipo:

```
tiempos = [
    {
        id: 39,
        nombre: "Juan",
        tiempos: [
            {
                vuelta: 1,
                tiempo: "16.15",
                terminado: 1
            },
            {
                vuelta: 2,
                tiempo: "16.07",
                terminado: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 40,
        nombre: "Pedro",
        tiempos: [
            {
                vuelta: 1,
                tiempo: "18.14",
                terminado: 1
            },
            {
                vuelta: 2,
                tiempo: "0",
                terminado: 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 41,
        nombre: "Paco",
        tiempos: [
            {
                vuelta: 1,
                tiempo: "17.32",
                terminado: 1
            },
            {
                vuelta: 2,
                tiempo: "0",
                terminado: 0
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Lo que necesito es filtrar por la propiedad "terminado" que sea igual a 1 del "segundo elemento" de la propiedad "tiempos".

Es decir, que solo me muestre los elementos que tengan "terminado: 1" en el segundo recorrido, para este ejemplo que solo muestre el objeto con id 39.

Utilizando

```
ng-if="(tiempos | filter: {})"
```

De antemano, gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la respuesta de @PabloLozano he tomado en cuenta que usas `angularJS`, no se si esto es lo que necesitas, quedo atento.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.tiempos = [
        {
            id: 39,
            nombre: "Juan",
            tiempos: [
                {
                    vuelta: 1,
                    tiempo: "16.15",
                    terminado: 1
                },
                {
                    vuelta: 2,
                    tiempo: "16.07",
                    terminado: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 40,
            nombre: "Pedro",
            tiempos: [
                {
                    vuelta: 1,
                    tiempo: "18.14",
                    terminado: 1
                },
                {
                    vuelta: 2,
                    tiempo: "0",
                    terminado: 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 41,
            nombre: "Paco",
            tiempos: [
                {
                    vuelta: 1,
                    tiempo: "17.32",
                    terminado: 1
                },
                {
                    vuelta: 2,
                    tiempo: "0",
                    terminado: 0
                }
            ]
        },
    ]

    $scope.resultado=$scope.tiempos.filter(elem => elem.tiempos[1] && elem.tiempos[1].terminado===1);
    console.log($scope.resultado);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-if="(tiempos|filter:resultado).length == 0">
                {{ resultado }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Actualizacion***

He actualizado la respuesta agregando lo siguiente en el `html`

```
ng-if="(tiempos|filter:resultado).length == 0"
```

Comment: En realidad lo que quiero es hacer el filtro dentro del ng-if, algo como ng-if="(tiempos | filter: {tiempos[1].terminado: 1})",

Comment: @Agares ya lo edite, puedes revisar, cualquier cosa de cuentas.

Answer (score 3):

Precisamente existe el método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) en la clase Array que hace justo lo que necesitas:

```js
const tiempos = [
    {
        id: 39,
        nombre: "Juan",
        tiempos: [
            {
                vuelta: 1,
                tiempo: "16.15",
                terminado: 1
            },
            {
                vuelta: 2,
                tiempo: "16.07",
                terminado: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 40,
        nombre: "Pedro",
        tiempos: [
            {
                vuelta: 1,
                tiempo: "18.14",
                terminado: 1
            },
            {
                vuelta: 2,
                tiempo: "0",
                terminado: 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 41,
        nombre: "Paco",
        tiempos: [
            {
                vuelta: 1,
                tiempo: "17.32",
                terminado: 1
            },
            {
                vuelta: 2,
                tiempo: "0",
                terminado: 0
            }
        ]
    },
]

const resultado=tiempos.filter(elem => elem.tiempos[1] && elem.tiempos[1].terminado===1);
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: ¿Y hay alguna forma de poner eso en la vista? algo como: ng-if(tiempos | filter: { })